# Proxy settings when i am not on wifi and using mobile data

Tags: performance, blazemeter

I need proxy setting to capture all requests of a mobile application to perform **performance testing with Blazemeter**.

Is there a way to configure, as i am not on wifi, i am confused how should i configure proxy in my mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder (Mobile And Web)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-) article for details.

In few words:

1. You get you own personal proxy in the cloud:

   [image: BlazeMeter Proxy]
2. You configure your mobile device to use that proxy.
3. When you click "Record" button (red one in the bottom) the proxy starts capturing requests from your mobile device
4. Once recording is done you can export the recorded test scenario in different formats including "SmartJMX" with automatic correlations applied

Comment: My question is related to second point, for wifi i know how to configure my mobile, but right now i am on mobile data, not sure how to configure it to use this proxy

Comment: It depends on the mobile operating system you use, for instance Android settings are described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14738791/2897748)

Comment: Thanks man, i am on 6.0 Android .That link solved my problem.